# Removing Support for iPad2 in iOS application

Tags: ios

The app am working on needs the latest device, so we are planning to remove support for iPad2 since the memory issues and performance issues. Due to development issues we have already removed support for iPhone. The app is ready to go to App store, so can some please help find a solution for this. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't. iPad 2 is still supported with iOS 9

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, other than to indirectly affect what devices you support by setting the Deployment Target, or front-facing camera, but neither of those will help you in this case.

Comment: your question is fine, but it affect in anyother way for other works, please ensure before do this